# How to implement an onboarding flow with page dots in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

**iOS noob** here so don't flame me too hard. :)

I am trying to implement a UIPageViewController that can swipe through for the following screens I have created in storyboard, in a popular tutorial form with page dots.

**Storyboard image below:**

[image]

I have tried to implement it this way (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/11/move-uipageviewcontroller-dots/) in a self-contained UIPageViewController; however, I am unsure how to do that because each screen requires the same facebook login functionality *(keep in mind the first screen has a different facebook button position than the last three)*

I have also attempted to use this library; however, to my experience, it is not relevant because I have **already** created each viewcontroller in the storyboard?

How exactly to go about achieving this?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the page view controller or how to overlay the facebook button over each page?

Comment: follow up to @Sebastian's comment: are you hoping for the button to "animate" down when you go from first to second screen?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for